# Will ArrayList grow dynamically if null is added?

Tags: java, arraylist

Assuming Java 8.

Default size of `ArrayList` is 10 (the size of array that stores data is 10 by default) and when 11th element is added to it size of array increases to 15.

Will it also increase if null is added at 11th position?

I know that calling `size()` on list will return `11`, but the question is whether the internal array will also grow?

Comment: Have you tried it? Verifying by trying/debugging is likely a lot quicker than asking on Stack Overflow. Also, why would you ever think it wouldn't grow? Whether you put in a null or an object, it would need storage to record that fact.

Comment: check the source code first,you can learn more from code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1); 
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

This is the implementation for the add function for Java's ArrayList. There is no condition to handle `null` objects, in which case it is treated as an ordinary object and added to the ArrayList. This will increase the size of the Collection as it still exists as an element.

This will also increase the internal size of the List.

Answer (score 3):

ArrayLists contains arrays of references to objects stored somewhere else (a place in memory called the heap). Therefore even if you add null its reference will cause internal array to grow.